# How to return empty when reducing a flux

Tags: project-reactor

Given this simplified sample code:

```
Flux.empty()
  .cast(Integer.class)
  .reduce(Integer.valueOf(1), (i,j) -> i+j)
  .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

How to achieve that the result of the reduce operation is also empty?

Answer (score 1):

You can't with this particular variant. Half the purpose of the `Integer.valueOf(1)` is to provide a seed that ensures there's a value even if the source is empty.

However you can use the variant without a seed/seed supplier:

```
Flux.empty()
  .cast(Integer.class)
  .reduce((i,j) -> i+j)
  .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

An empty sequence or single-valued sequence will be reproduced as-is (the javadoc is maybe a bit unclear on that), so:

- the code above would produce an empty `Mono`.
- replacing `Flux.empty().cast(Integer.class)` with `Flux.just(1)` would produce a `Mono` that emits `1`.
- replacing with `Flux.just(3, 4)` would produce a `Mono` that emits `7`

Comment: > You can't with this particular variant<

Hmm yeah and I need the variant where the output type is not the input type